# Record Not found Couldn't find Contrato with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to export a docx file using caracal but I'm getting a routing error, but everything seems to be okay. 
I did this 3 days ago exactly like now and worked, now I'm getting an error. 
Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'grayscale/index'

  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'registrar'}
  resources :contratos
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'contratos#index'

  get 'contratos/page'
end
```

contratos_controller.rb

```
class ContratosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_contrato, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :export, :page]
  access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all
  require './lib/generate_pdf'

  # GET /contratos
  # GET /contratos.json
  def index
    @contratos = Contrato.all
  end

  # GET /contratos/1
  # GET /contratos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contratos/new
  def new
    @contrato = Contrato.new
  end

  # GET /contratos/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  def page
    Caracal::Document.save(Rails.root.join("public", "example.docx")) do |docx|
      # page 1
      docx.h1 'Page 1 Header'
      docx.hr
      docx.p
      docx.h2 'Section 1'
      docx.p  'Lorem ipsum dolor....'
      docx.p
    end
    path = File.join(Rails.root, "public")
    send_file(File.join(path, "example.docx")
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Generate Docx', contratos_page_path %>
```

The full error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ContratosController#show
Couldn't find Contrato with 'id'=page

    def set_contrato
      @contrato = Contrato.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common beginner issue which is due to the fact that routes have precedence in the order they are declared (thus the comment on top of routes.rb).

Since `resources :contratos` already defines a `GET /contratos/:id` route it will always match the request for `GET /contratos/page` to `contratos#show`. Rails does not assume that your ids are numerical when routing. These paths will all match the `GET /contratos/:id` route:

```
GET /contratos/1
GET /contratos/page
GET /contratos/page?foo=bar
GET /contratos/foo-bar-baz
GET /contratos/alksjd-usfiugi%-dfgd
```

But these will not:

```
GET /contratos/new # declared before the show route
GET /contratos/1/foo
GET /contratos/foo/bar
```

You can fix this by moving your custom route to the top:

```
get 'contratos/page'
resources :contratos
```

But there is a better Rails way of [adding additional restful actions to a resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :contratos do
  get :page, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: I moved the "get 'contratos/page' to the top and worked. Many thanks lad.

Comment: Thats the wrong takeaway here. But whatever keeps your leaky boat floating I guess...